# SSL exception for single folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate, prestashop

I would like to remove my `SSL` only for one folder.

My url is `https://www.example.com`
and I would like to remove https for my interactive PDF `https://www.example.com/catalog2017` because https does not work with my interactive PDF.

I tried with `.htaccess` but not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following rules in your `.htaccess` file. What this does is first check if HTTPs is not on, if not, then it will forward everything to HTTPs except for the directory `catalog2017`. The second rule checks if HTTPs is on, if so then it will redirect `catalog2017` back to HTTP.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(catalog2017)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(catalog2017)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this. If you have problems with the above rule, then you can also try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalog2017
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog2017
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)