# Htaccess redirect to https except ads.txt

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect all traffic on my site to HTTPS except for the ads.txt file. Note it's to a file e.g. domain.com/ads.txt and not a sub-folder such as domain.com/all-files-in-here/

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ads.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This isn't working according to the testing tool at https://adstxt.adnxs.com

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Kind regards

James

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL exception for single folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114498/ssl-exception-for-single-folder)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I was unable to find an acceptable answer for what Google Adsense require.

"Make an ads.txt file reachable via both HTTP and HTTPS"

This works for me...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads\.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When the protocol is HTTP you want to convert every url to HTTPS except "/ads.txt".

When the protocol is HTTPS you dont need to convert any url.

This provides the required outcome to have ads.txt load on both HTTP and HTTPS.

Cheers

Greg J